# "core:propertyTypes:warn "#bot" asset not found. " - aframe-master.js

Tags: reactjs, aframe, ar.js

Started recently using aframe and ar.js with react. Worked like a charm so far. Unfortunately now a gltf model wont load.

Here is my scene:

```
<a-scene
        vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;"
        arjs="debugUIEnabled: false; patternRatio: 0.70"
        device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: true">

          <a-assets timeout='3000'>
            <a-asset-item id="bot" src="url(/assets/robot_walking/scene.gltf)"></a-asset-item>
          </a-assets>

          <a-marker type="pattern" url="markers/07ratio/fly/pattern-fly.patt" id="m3" registermarker >
            <a-entity
              id="hat"
              gltf-model="#bot"
              animation-mixer
              visible="true"
              scale="0.05 0.05 0.05"
              position="0 0 0"
              rotation="0 0 0">
            </a-entity>
          </a-marker>

          <a-entity camera look-controls id="camera"></a-entity>

      </a-scene>
```

It is rendered inside a react component. Aframe and Ar.js have been installed using npm.
It already worked with a different gltf using

```
gltf-mode="url(/assets/sun_straw_hat/scene.gltf)"
```

inline. That model didn't have any animations and was not as large. But I couldn't use the asset manager there either. Does someone know what I am doing wrong here? So far I tried importing aframe-extras, importing afram and ar.js with `<script>` tags in the index.html, using src instead of gltf-model, using `<a-gltf-model>` with src, and varying the asset timeout. No luck with any of that.

kind regards
Orys

Comment: Is it working outside of react (or without arjs for that matter)?

Comment: Hey Piotr, thanks for your quick reply. I ran it without, ar.js and react and it worked fine (with animations). With ar.js the textures where a litte off but it still worked (also with animations). Found out, that the scale is much smaller then the previous model. Now its showing in react as well. But the animations still don't work and I still have to import it without the asset manager. (aframe-extras i imported in react is the same version as imported with the <script> tag)

Comment: any chance you could throw a minimal example on [glitch](https://glitch.com/~aframe)? Do the animations work without react, or they wont work at all?

Comment: ah now its working ... simply had to add 'clip: *; ' to the animation mixer. Thanks a lot for the reply. Wouldnt have seen that it is too small if not for the white background of the aframe-only scene. ^^

Comment: glad it's working :) Have fun with a-frame!

Comment: Here is the [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/nosy-prairie-apogee). The marker is in the assets folder. cant get the model working. Glitch wont upload the textures folder of the gltf so I converted the model to glb. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Did you check the model with [Don's Viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/)? The glb seems to have some errors. Is the non-coverted gltf working properly in the viewer?

Comment: No errors in Dons Viewer using the gltf. Seems like the converter I used sucks ... there are still some texture problems with the gltf using ar.js

Comment: upload the gltf, bin + textures to the glitch, I'll try to figure it out

Comment: Hey Piotr, sorry for the wait. I updated glitch with the gltf, bin and texture files.

Comment: Also invited you to the github repo of this project. If you are interested. It's still quite a mess though.

Comment: I may have something figured out,  I've made a remix to freely mess around if you don't mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be simplifing much, but afaik:

---

Typically, in a setup like this:

```
<a-assets>
  <a-asset-item id="model" src="scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>
<a-entity gltf-model="#model"></a-entity>
```

the `gltf-model` component assumes that the `<a-asset-item>` node is ready. But react has it's own [algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#motivation) of [when to render which node](https://imkev.dev/react-rendering-order#demo).

Because the `gltf-model` can't query the `#model` node, you get the error:

```
core:propertyTypes:warn "#bot" asset not found.
```

I suppose we can either:

**1) load the model directly from an url**

```
gltf-model="url(path_to_model.gltf)"
```

which should be working properly ([as it is in this remix of your glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-70281029-url?path=src%2Fapp.jsx%3A28%3A32)):

[image]

**2) try to render the `a-assets` node before the [gltf-model] one**

There probably are better ways, but I've:

1. put the marker + camera in another react component (i.e. `<Scene>`)
2. keep track of the when the scene + assets are mounted

   ```
     class App extends React.Component {

       constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {assetsReady: false};
       }
       componentDidMount() {
         this.setState({assetsReady: true});
         // for whatever reason i need to set it manually?
         this.state.assetsReady = true
       }
   ```
3. use a conditional to render the `<Scene/>`when mounted:

   ```
   <a-scene>
     <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="model" 
                      src="https://cdn.glitch.me/fc511399-d148-4898-ad51-f0b6fafd32a6/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>  
        </a-assets>
      {
          // this is inside Apps render() function
          this.state.assetsReady == true &&
          <Scene />
      }            
   </a-scene>
   ```

check it out in [this remix of your glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-70281029-assets?path=src%2Fapp.jsx%3A35%3A47) which also seems to be working:

[image]

---

The model is glitching because of the scale (scale the model 30 - 50 times) - a simple solution is using a [logarithmic depth buffer](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/renderer.html#logarithmicdepthbuffer):

```
<a-scene renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true"></a-scene>
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. Putting the entity in a separate component did not only solve the problem, but the code looks much cleaner now as well.